# gpupdate /force stuck at "updating policy ..."

Tags: dns, updates, group-policy

I added a new Windows 11 computer in my domain recently, it's the first win11 operating system.
I tried to update his policy with : gpupdate /force
but the command is running for hours and never stops,
on my other computers (win10), it works perfecly.
I checked the windows logs but nothing is interesting about group_policy
How can i solve this problem ?
Louis,

i tried to update his policy with : gpupdate /force
i tried to reinstall win 11 on the machine, add it to the domain, but same problem.